# Removing lines that are not horizontally or vertically straight with Python cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a test automation project where I try to detect what object is selected in an app visually using OpenCV. I have made considerable progress using Canny edge detection. Problem is I can't get it accurate enough when there are background graphics and similar in the image.

Since I'm looking for a box that marks a selection and the only thing I'm really interested in is finding where in the image that box is, I am hoping to achieve this by removing all lines or shapes in the image that are not vertically or horizontally straight.

What (if any) would be the best way of achieving this? I have spend almost the whole day Googling and experimenting with different methods, especially Hough lines, but have so far not managed to reach the result I want.

I'm using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 2.4.9

See the images below.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y7TX.png)

[the result I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgfhV.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried a [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/dd7/tutorial_morph_lines_detection.html) from opencv? Note that you can select required language on the page (c++|java|python).

Answer (score 0):

If your lines are actually axis-aligned and you have some minimum cutoff length of the lines you could do something primitive like:

1. Create some 2d-array which will act like a mask (let's call it `keep`), initialize to `0`
2. Optional: Do something like dilation to fill in tiny gaps in lines
3. Walk through the image row by row and detect contiguous white horizontal lines (black to white transition is a start, and white to black transition is end, image edges are special cases)
4. If lines are longer than the cutoff, mark that line (start to end in current row) with `1` in `keep`
5. Do 3-4 but with columns instead of rows
6. Apply mask

Not sure how well that would work in general, but it's a good first try.

There probably good ways to do this within opencv (like mentioned in the comments to the question), but I'm not well versed enough with all it covers to say anything about that.

## Proof of concept

Here is a some slow code just as a PoC, doing pixel by pixel work in python is a bad idea, but it shows the idea. Using PIL, but considering I'm just doing pixel access here it shouldn't be hard to rewrite.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('3Y7TX.png')
n,m = im.height,im.width

keep = [[0]*m for _ in range(n)]

cutoff = 50

def iswhite(i,j):
    return im.getpixel((j,i))[0] == 255

# Fill some holes
for i in range(1,n-1):
    for j in range(1,m-1):
        #  t
        # lcr
        #  b
        t = iswhite(i-1,j)
        b = iswhite(i+1,j)
        l = iswhite(i,j-1)
        r = iswhite(i,j+1)
        c = iswhite(i,j)

        if t == b == True or l == r == True:
            im.putpixel((j,i), (255,255,255,255))

# Detect horizontal lines
for i in range(n):
    start = None
    inline = False

    for j in range(m):
        white = iswhite(i,j)

        if inline:
            # Line end check
            if not white:
                inline = False
                if j - start >= cutoff:
                    for x in range(start,j):
                        keep[i][x] = 1

        else:
            # Line start check
            if white:
                inline = True
                start = j
    if inline:
        if m - start >= cutoff:
            for x in range(start,m):
                keep[i][x] = 1

# Detect vertical lines
for j in range(m):
    start = None
    inline = False

    for i in range(n):
        white = iswhite(i,j)

        if inline:
            # Line end check
            if not white:
                inline = False
                if i - start >= cutoff:
                    for x in range(start,i):
                        keep[x][j] = 1

        else:
            # Line start check
            if white:
                inline = True
                start = i
    if inline:
        if n - start >= cutoff:
            for x in range(start,n):
                keep[x][j] = 1

# Apply mask
for i in range(im.height):
    for j in range(im.width):
        if not keep[i][j]:
            im.putpixel((j,i), (0,0,0,255))

im.save('poc.png')
```

### Before and after

image: [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y7TX.png)

image: [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ390.png)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. I've looked into both these methods but none of them have proved to be sufficently reliable. They sometimes work but not often enough. I'll have to find some other solution for my problem.